RelativeLayout the root element for a list-item layout not showing bottom margin
I am creating a list-item layout for a ListView, when I set marginBootom for the root element which ia a RelativeLayout the margin is not effective. What could be the reason?
Below is my code:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="4dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/primaryActionIcon"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/primary_action_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_document" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/primaryActionIcon"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="Dummy text" />

